# PHP export csv file

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to export csv file but when i export file it generates chienese text in csv.

```
public function actionExportFile()
{
       header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
       $list = array (
                array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
                array('123', '456', '789'),
                array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
                );

                $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

                foreach ($list as $fields) {
                    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
                }

                fclose($fp);
        exit;
    }
```

What i am doing wrong to export csv.

Comment: What's wrong?  What does this do?  Did this create a `file.csv`?  What's in the file?  Do you see any errors?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mixing 2 uses of PHP with header and file writing.
Either remove the `header` line to write to a file on the server :

```
function actionExportFile()
{
   $list = array (
            array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
            array('123', '456', '789'),
            array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
            );

            $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

            foreach ($list as $fields) {
                fputcsv($fp, $fields);
            }

            fclose($fp);
    exit;
}
```

or change your code to:

```
function actionExportFile()
{
   header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
   $list = array (
            array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
            array('123', '456', '789'),
            array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
            );

            foreach ($list as $fields) {
            echo implode( ',', $fields );
         }
    exit;
}
```

to produce a file download.